# Integration involving x at the power and the gamma function

Tags: integration, special-functions

Suppose a nonnegative function $f$ on the positive real line and $f(x)\neq\Gamma(x)$. Do we know any closed formula of the following integral
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^+} \frac{\alpha^x}{\Gamma(x)}f(x)dx,$$
where $\alpha>0$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a table entry for the Laplace transform ($\alpha -> s $) of the integral.  Which is slightly simpler but ... involves the Laplace xform of f(x)->F(s); as F(ln(s)).  So would involve a somewhat complex inversion.  Would that entry be of any help?

Comment: Are you saying that consider this integral as a Laplace transform with parameter -Ln(\alpha)? Yeah, this seems to be a good way. Then, which entry shall I start from?

Comment: Yes that's a possibility and I might have a paper somewhere that helps but I was refering to $$\mathcal{L}_{t\rightarrow s}\left({\displaystyle \intop_{u=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{u-1}}{\Gamma\left(u\right)}f(u)du}\right)=\left[\mathcal{L}_{u\rightarrow t}\left(f(u)\right)\right]_{t=ln\left(s\right)}$$  From Caltech, a compilation of Bateman's work: https://authors.library.caltech.edu/43489/   In particular Vol 1 Tables of Integral Transforms  -> Laplace Transform -> General Formulas -.(29) .

Comment: But the notion of F(ln(s)) seems to be tied to a Laplace->Mellin mapping.  If you're interested, I have a reference but would have to study it to use it.  "Generalized Integral Transforms" by A.H. Zeeman, Theorem 4.2-1.  I will insert it here if you like but it might end up being irrelevant.

Comment: Now, it is crystal. Many thanks for this idea.I have not heard this book before. So, yes, could you please insert it here. Really nice to meet you.

Comment: From “Generalized Functions”, A.H. Zemanian

Theorem 4.2.1 Let $x=e^{-t}$. The Mapping  $$\theta\left(x\right)\mapsto e^{-t}\theta\left(e^{-t}\right)\triangleq\phi\left(t\right)$$is an isomorphis from $\mathbb{\mathcal{M}}_{a,b}\, into\,\mathcal{L}_{a,b}$. It is also an  
 isomorphism  from

$\mathcal{M}\left(w,z\right)\,onto\,\mathcal{L}\left(w,z\right)$. The inverse mapping is given by   $$\phi\left(t\right)\mapsto x^{-1}\phi\left(-log\left(x\right)\right)=\theta\left(x\right)$$  A "teaser" since it will take me some time to refresh the real meaning.